# How to create a JSON Array with the div data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Inside myordersdiv, I have all this below div's appended to it .

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <div class="prd-items-detials">
      <ul>
         <li class="head">
            <form><label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + itemname + '</label></form>
         </li>
         <li class="prd-items-qt">
            <div class="col"><span class="prd-sm-img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="' + image + '"/><span></div>
            <div class="col"><i class="minus" id_attr="' + id_attr_val + '"></i><i class="qt qt_' + id_attr_val + '" id_attr="' + id_attr_val + '">1</i><i class="plus" id_attr="' + id_attr_val + '"></i></div>
            <div class="col"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">Topping</a></div>
            <div style="display: none;" class="price" id_attr="' + id_attr_val + '">' + price + '</div>
            <div class="col total total_' + id_attr_val + '" id_attr="' + id_attr_val + '">' + price + '</div>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

**HTML Section .**

```
 <div id="myordersdiv">
 </div>
```

On click of a Confirm Order Button , I need to get all the images and its corresponding quantity and price present in that div , in below format

```
var divdata = '{"data": [{"name": "JSON_images/popcorn.jpg","quan":"1","price":"50"},{"name": "JSON_images/icecream_cup.jpg","quan":"2","price":"100"}]}';
```

Right now i am able to get all the images present under that div .

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-confirmorder", function () {
   var imagedata = $("#myordersdiv").find('img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src')
}).get()
```

The screen look this way .

[image]

I have seen this logic for creating an JSON array:

```
var divdata = {
    data: []
};

for(var i in someData) {

    var item = someData[i];

    divdata.data.push({ 
        "image" : item.firstName,
        "price"  : item.lastName,
        "quantity"     : item.age 
    });
}
```

please tell me how can i do all this under the listener ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't really figure out which of the elements holds what, so for the sake of displaying the algorithm I will go with: *quantity* is in a div having the class `quantity`, the *price* is in a div having the class `total` and each element is in its own `prd-items-detials` class div.

```
var divdata = {
     data: []
};    
var price, quantity, name;

// Iterate through each element
$.each($('.prd-items-detials'), function(i, elem) {
    price = $(elem).find('.total').html(); // The price is the inner HTML of the DIV with class 'total'
    quantity = $(elem).find('.quantity').html(); // The quantity is the inner HTML of the DIV with class 'quantity'
    name = $(elem).find('img').attr('src'); // The name is the 'src' attribute of the image

    divdata.data.push({ 
         "image": name,
         "price": price,
         "quantity": quantity 
    });
});
```

Please change the classes accordingly where necessary to get the information based on where your data is located.

P.S. You made a typo with *detials*, I think you were looking for *details*.

Comment: Thank you very much , i require this .